# MediaQuery.of(context) не работает

Tags: flutter, dart

**НЕ РАБОТАЕТ, ОШИБКА**

> width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2, height:
>   MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,

**НЕ РАБОТАЕТ, МОЖНО ТОЛЬКО ВЫВЕСТИ НА ЭКРАН ЗНАЧЕНИЯ**

> width: window.physicalSize.width / 2, height:
>   window.physicalSize.height / 2,

***main.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui';

void main() async {
 runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 //объявление переменных

 //вызывается один раз при инициализации виджета
 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();

 }

 void _f1(double value) {
  setState(() {

  });
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: Stack(
     children: <Widget>[
      Align(
       alignment: Alignment.center,
       child: Container(

        //НЕ РАБОТАЕТ, ОШИБКА
        //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
        //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,

        //НЕ РАБОТАЕТ, МОЖНО ТОЛЬКО ВЫВЕСТИ НА ЭКРАН ЗНАЧЕНИЯ
        width: window.physicalSize.width / 2,
        height: window.physicalSize.height / 2,

        color: Colors.pink,
       ),
      ),
     ],
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

Если кто-то сталкивался с такой ошибкой, подскажите. Спасибо.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так конечно не правильно работает, если у вас виджет не правильно построен (`window.physicalSize` используется только для того чтобы узнать физически размеры экрана, его не следует использовать как вы хотите):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Name App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Name Page'),
        ),
        body: MyApp(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
            color: Colors.pink,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Уважаемый MiT, ошибка, которая на фото, вот она: //НЕ РАБОТАЕТ, ОШИБКА
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2, Я ее закоментировал.

Comment: @Anton ну я её починил, посмотрите мой код.

Comment: Уваажаемый MiT, почему мой код не работает? Если убрать второй вариант (//НЕ РАБОТАЕТ, МОЖНО ТОЛЬКО ВЫВЕСТИ НА ЭКРАН ЗНАЧЕНИЯ
        width: window.physicalSize.width / 2,
        height: window.physicalSize.height / 2,) и расскомментировать 1 вариант? Вы пробовали? Именно мой код?

Comment: @Anton или просто попробуйте поставить в width/height цифры в вашем коде, вы получите такую же ошибку.

Comment: Да цифры работают, не работает //НЕ РАБОТАЕТ, ОШИБКА
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,

Comment: 2 вариант не работает, но ошибки красного экрана не выдает width: window.physicalSize.width / 2, height: window.physicalSize.height / 2,

Comment: @Anton цифры точно работают, у меня не работали...

Comment: Ваш код работает, мой код не работает. У меня в одном виджете MaterialApp.

Comment: @Anton объясню почему не работает, чтобы получить размеры через Media нам необходимо обратиться к контексту виджета. Но в вашем случае контекст за MaterialApp, по этому и нет размеров. В моем случае я обращаюсь к контексту MaterialApp, он уже знаете о размере экрана. MaterialApp это начало для всех остальных виджетов и по умолчанию имеет размер полного экрана.

Comment: Уважаемый MiT, огромное Вам спасибо.

Comment: @Anton пожалуйста!

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, мой код, где все в одном виджете, не совсем правильный. Он работает, но лучше так не использовать.

Comment: @Anton для данной задачи, да, не подходит.